# How come the use of delay differential equations in model parameter estimation better than ordinary differential equations?

Tags: pde, ode, computational-biology

in systems biology why is the use of delay differential equations better than ordinary differential equations i.e. compartment models in delay modelling? is there a data independence angle in models parameter estimation?

Comment: Systems biology is a large field, and I doubt that the *whole* field finds delay DEs better than ODEs. In other words, your question doesn't really have enough information for anyone to help you, unless you augment it with examples and specifics.

Comment: I meant in delay modelling for example drugs whose effect is only observed after a delay

Comment: @Wazaa Well, if you observe some delay, it stands to reason that your model should also include some delay, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes and delay can be included through odes by building a system of odes where each ode will represent a delay compartment...of course it supposes a fitting to experimental data to estimate the delays....however users of DDEs seem to say that delays estimated through ddes instead are better because they are less sensitive to change in experimental data i.e. variability be it known or residual